# JBOSS EAP 6.1 setting JNDI env variable using jboss-ejb3.xml is not working

Tags: jboss, jndi, logback

I am trying to set the JNDI env-entries logback/context-name and app_name in jboss_ejb3.xml which is under META-INF.But when I deploy my ear file log back is unable to read the JNDI env entry.

****jboss-ejb3.xml file:****

```
 <?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss:ejb-jar xmlns:jboss="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:c="urn:clustering:1.0"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-ejb3-2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
               version="3.1"
               impl-version="2.0">
    <enterprise-beans>
     <session>
        <ejb-name>TestLogBean</ejb-name>
     <env-entry>
        <description>JNDI logging context for this app</description>
        <env-entry-name>logback/context-name</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>yoda</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
        <env-entry>
        <description>Application name</description>
        <env-entry-name>app_name</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>SampleLogger</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>




    </session>
    </enterprise-beans>
</jboss:ejb-jar>
```

When I deploy the ear file, log back is throwing the following exception

> [Server:server-two] *[0m*[0m02:07:20,352 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service
>   thread 1-11) 02:07:20,352 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.InsertFromJNDIAction -
>   [java:comp/env/app_name] has null or empty value_[0m
>   [Server:server-two] *[0m*[0m02:07:20,353 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service
>   thread 1-11) 02:07:20,352 |-ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.InsertFromJNDIAction -
>   [java:comp/env/app_name] has null or empty value_[0m

logback.xml File :

```
<configuration debug="true">
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:comp/env/app_name" as="app_name" />
<property name="messagePattern" value="%d [%thread] %-5level ${app_name}.%logger{46} - %msg%n"/>
 <appender name="CON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
     <Pattern>JNDI-TEST %d %-5level %msg %logger{50}%n</Pattern>
   </layout>
 </appender>

<root level="DEBUG">
   <appender-ref ref="CON" />
 </root>

</configuration>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pass   -Dlogback.ContextSelector=JNDI  vm args while starting JBOSS server.